# Проблема с установкой Composer на Debian 8

Tags: yii2, debian, composer

Хочу установить себе Composer, что бы через него ставить yii
Запускаю установку командой

```
curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Через некоторе время получаю ошибку

```
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

В чем может быть проблема? Обращался к хостеру, говорит, что проблем сети нету

Comment: приложите вывод двух команд: `$ wget -S --spider https://getcomposer.org/versions` и `$ wget -4 -S --spider https://getcomposer.org/versions`

Comment: там проблема была в том, что надо было раскоментить строку в файле gai.conf

Comment: @Diefair какую именно строку?

Answer (score 1):

Изначально приоритет у ipv6 выше чем у ipv4 и по этому при обращении к https://getcomposer.org/versions первый запрашиваемым будет адрес ipv6. Для изменения приоритета ipv4 над ipv6 нужно внести изменения в файл /etc/gai.conf:

CentOS

```
 # vi /etc/gai.conf
 precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```

Debian раскоментировать строку в /etc/gai.conf:

```
#    For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
#
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

После этого можно снова пробовать установить Composer